# Jbehave selenium - verifyEquals is not marking the step as failed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, bdd, jbehave

I am using selenium webdriver with Jbehave to automate tests using BDD, and I have a problem regarding verifying values. I need my tests not to immediately fail after an assertion not equals as expected. Instead, I want my test to verify each value, and then if at least one assertion has failed, my step needs to be marked as failure.

I am using verifyEquals, which doesn't terminate the tests after immediately find an assertion failure, but continues instead.

My problem is, if one or more values do not successfully match as expected, my step is not marked as failure, and I have to go to the console to discover if it has some value mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should change your test architecture.
For any test frameworks that also have a `verify` feature that doesn't stop the test, you should terminate your tests with an `Assert` statement.
Verify is used only to validate some prerequisites to what the test is actually testing.
If you take for example a test where you test that the order amount is correct, you could go with the following:

1. `verify` name is correct
2. `verify` email is correct
3. `assert` order amount is correct

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `verify`, it is better to `Assert`s from the Junit library. You can even customize you assert by using a try catch block and decide on whether to continue the test by printing the error or stop the test.